# Unable to deploy spring boot application to weblogic server

Tags: spring-boot, weblogic12c

**Issue :**

Unable to deploy Spring-Boot application in WebLogic Server.

**Description**

I am new to Spring boot trying to build a proxy application to route the requests to source system but having issues deploying to weblogic-12c. It's a very simple application that exposes a rest service and then redirects the received request to upstream system.

**What did I try ?**

Tried log4j version in pom.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml approaches googling, I've also read the issue is b'coz of the data sources but I don't have any persistence logic and don't need a data source to be configured in weblogic.

Below is the error I am seeing, any suggestions are highly appreciated.

**ERROR:**

```
Unable to access the selected application.
Message icon - Error java.io.IOException
Message icon - Error weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException
```

Comment: Please provide the steps you are following to deploy your app and the full stack trace of your deployment error.

Comment: Try this and let us know if you are still unsuccessful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084670/error-while-uploading-springboot-war-file-to-weblogic-12-2-1-3-server