# (Weblogic 12c) From RFC 2068 10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error while executing request from Soap ui

Tags: java, spring, weblogic12c

I have devloped spring ws webservice.I am able to deploy war in tomcat and load wsdl.
But same war when i am deploying in weblogic 12c.Applcation is in active state.
I am able to import wsdl in soapui. But when i hit request i am getting  below error is coming in soap ui. In tomcat every operation is working fine

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Draft//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error 500--Internal Server Error</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="white">
<FONT FACE=Helvetica><BR CLEAR=all>
<TABLE border=0 cellspacing=5><TR><TD><BR CLEAR=all>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica" COLOR="black" SIZE="3"><H2>Error 500--Internal Server Error</H2>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>
<TABLE border=0 width=100% cellpadding=10><TR><TD VALIGN=top WIDTH=100% BGCOLOR=white><FONT FACE="Courier New"><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H3>From RFC 2068 <i>Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1</i>:</H3>
</FONT><FONT FACE="Helvetica" SIZE="3"><H4>10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error</H4>
</FONT><P><FONT FACE="Courier New">The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.</FONT></P>
</FONT></TD></TR>
</TABLE>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What is the exception in the WebLogic console logs?

Comment: Server log no error is coming

Comment: Above information is not sufficient to help. There is definitely some kind of fault generated by server. Is there anything in app logs? Is it possible to create a smaller demo app for troubleshooting?

Comment: In have put logger .Log file is generated in tomcat and statement are logged fine. But in weblogic  logfile is not getting generated.I created manually but still statement are not logged .Can you guide me on this I am new to weblogic

Comment: Can you follow these steps and see if a demo app is working to rule out environment issues? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084670/error-while-uploading-springboot-war-file-to-weblogic-12-2-1-3-server/65114013#65114013

Comment: i tried as per the link shared i am getting below error  An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
Message icon - Error [J2EE:160144]Failed to register library Extension-Name: demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Library cannot have Implementation-Version set, without also specifying its Specification-Version

Comment: @Tushar can you guide me on this.i am new to weblogic

Comment: Please create a GitHub repo to troubleshoot.

Comment: Please find my github repo https://github.com/vatsalnarry2/myRnd.git